# Angular 9: Animations Not Triggering

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angular-animations

I have a <job-list> component which contains several <job-line> components. Each <job-line> has an underlying `job` object. I set up an animation trigger to show a pulsing effect when a `recentlyEdited` flag on the `job` object is true.

The `[@newIncomingJob]` animation isn't triggering even though the flag is being set correctly. I've been following the Angular animation tutorials closely so I'm not sure why it wouldn't trigger.

job-line-animation.ts

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';
    export function startPulse() {
        return trigger('newIncomingJob', [
      state('normal', style({ backgroundColor:"red"  })),
      state('updating', style({ backgroundColor: "white",height:"200px" })),
        transition('void => updating', [
        animate('5s 0s ease-in')
      ]),
      transition('updating => normal', [
        animate('5s 0s ease-in')
      ])
    ])
    }
```

job-list.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let job of jobsFromBackend | async">
  <button (click)="testPulseAnimation(job)">Test Pulse Animation. Current State: {{job.recentlyEdited ? 'updating' : 'normal'}}</button>
<job-line
 [job]="job" 
[@newIncomingJob]="job.recentlyEdited ? 'updating' : 'normal'">
</job-line>
</div>
</mat-accordion>
</div>
```

job-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'job-list',
  templateUrl: './job-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-list.component.css'],
  animations: [startPulse()]
})


export class JobListComponent implements OnInit {
/*
...
*/
testPulseAnimation(job): void {
      job.recentlyEdited=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding `[@newIncomingJob]="job.recentlyEdited ? 'updating' : 'normal'"` to a top level HTML tag in job-line.component.html